# Magnify effect for sprite not working properly

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm working on a 2d game in Unity. I would like my sprite to slightly increase in size and then back to normal (loop it). So basically it's a magnifying effect on a loop. It's something for a loading screen unity2d. I have the following code, but it doesn't seem to work.

Any idea on what I've done wrong? Any advice is very much appreciated, thank you!

```
using UnityEngine;

public class SpriteFader : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private float delayTime = 1f;
    [SerializeField] private float fadeInTime = 1f;
    [SerializeField] private float stayVisibleTime = 5f;
    [SerializeField] private float fadeOutTime = 1f;
    [SerializeField] private AudioClip fadeInSound;
    [SerializeField] private float minScale = 1f;
    [SerializeField] private float maxScale = 1.2f;
    [SerializeField] private float scaleSpeed = 0.1f;

    private SpriteRenderer spriteRenderer;
    private float fadeDirection = 1f;
    private float timer = 0f;
    private bool hasFadedIn = false;
    private bool hasStartedFadeOut = false;
    private bool hasStartedDelay = false;
    private AudioSource audioSource;
    private bool isScalingUp = false;

    void Start()
    {
        spriteRenderer = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
        spriteRenderer.color = new Color(spriteRenderer.color.r, spriteRenderer.color.g, spriteRenderer.color.b, 0f);

        audioSource = gameObject.AddComponent<AudioSource>();
        audioSource.playOnAwake = false;
        audioSource.clip = fadeInSound;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (!hasStartedDelay)
        {
            // Wait for the delay time to elapse
            if (timer < delayTime)
            {
                timer += Time.deltaTime;
            }
            else
            {
                hasStartedDelay = true;
                timer = 0f;

                // Play the fadeInSound when delay is over
                audioSource.Play();
            }
        }
        else if (!hasFadedIn)
        {
            // Fade in the sprite
            float newAlpha = spriteRenderer.color.a + (Time.deltaTime / fadeInTime);
            spriteRenderer.color = new Color(spriteRenderer.color.r, spriteRenderer.color.g, spriteRenderer.color.b, newAlpha);

            if (newAlpha >= 1f)
            {
                hasFadedIn = true;
                isScalingUp = true;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // Wait for the stay visible time before starting to fade out
            if (timer < stayVisibleTime)
            {
                timer += Time.deltaTime;
                if (isScalingUp)
                {
                    float newScale = Mathf.Lerp(minScale, maxScale, scaleSpeed);
                    transform.localScale = new Vector3(newScale, newScale, 1f);
                    if (newScale >= maxScale)
                    {
                        isScalingUp = false;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    float newScale = Mathf.Lerp(maxScale, minScale, scaleSpeed);
                    transform.localScale = new Vector3(newScale, newScale, 1f);
                    if (newScale <= minScale)
                    {
                        isScalingUp = true;
                    }
                }
            }
            else if (!hasStartedFadeOut)
            {
                hasStartedFadeOut = true;
                fadeDirection = -1f;
                timer = 0f;
            }
            else
            {
                // Fade out the sprite
                float newAlpha = spriteRenderer.color.a + (Time.deltaTime / fadeOutTime * fadeDirection);
                spriteRenderer.color = new Color(spriteRenderer.color.r, spriteRenderer.color.g, spriteRenderer.color.b, newAlpha);

                if (newAlpha <= 0f)
                {
                    // Destroy the game object after fading out
                    Destroy(gameObject);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You'll need to reduce this down to a specific problem instead of just asking "why does my 100+ line script not work?". Which part of it is not working? Seems like a lot of code for a simple idea. You could probably replace all of this with an `Animator` component, or at least move it into a coroutine.

Comment: So it's a script which I added as component to a sprite. It's supposed to increase size and then decrease, but somehow for me it's not doing anything, it's just idle.